# Efficient conversion of a dataframe into list in a large dataset

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following code that reads in a csv file(into `dataset` DataFrame) and convert this into a list(into `transactions` list) to be processed by an apriori algorithm.

```
import pandas as pd

dataset = pd.read_csv('datasetFile.csv')
transactions = []
num_rows = 8000
num_cols = 20
for i in range(0, num_rows):
    transactions.append([str(dataset.values[i,j]) for j in range(0, num_cols)])
```

The format of the .csv file is 8000 rows, with a maximum of 20 products in a row:

```
bread, butter
bread, milk, eggs, fruit
milk
eggs, milk, bread
```

The above python code works for this small dataset. However, my current dataset has around 300k rows and 300 cols. How can I improve this piece of python code to convert the large DataFrame into a list?

Comment: in each row is more values as `num_cols` ? Or less, so no problem ig get  `NaN`s ?

Comment: yes, if i understood you correctly. In most rows the value would be NaN.

Comment: OK, one small thing, `dataset = pd.read_csv('datasetFile.csv')` working nice? first row is the longest?

Comment: Yes, although large, that line seem to be okay. For the larger dataset, I actually have `gc.enable()` and `gc.disable()` around it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe need filter values, convert to numpy array and then to list:

```
transactions = dataset.iloc[:num_rows, :num_cols].astype(str).values.tolist()
```

Comment: Great! This is so much more faster! May I ask why this is faster?

Comment: @Jay - because vectorized operation - no loops.